# javascript if class x contains z get link of class y

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, applescript

i'm no js expert but need to execute some js in my applescript. Don't know if this is possible as the html page contains several instances of this div class.

1. **If** nested div class ".product_card__title" contains "my search term"
2. **Extract href** link from nested class ".js-search-product-link"
3. **From main div** with the class ".product_card"

A ANLTERNATIVE VERSION TO THE ONE ACCEPTED HERE [IN THIS THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357012/javascript-remove-null-from-the-result).

My Html:

```
<div class="product_card powersearch__product_card">
     <a href="/shop/XYZ" class="js-search-product-link">
  <div class="product_card__image" style="background-image:url(https://image.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="product_card__title">SEARCH FOR THIS TITLE</div>
  <div class="product_card__meta">€14</div></a></div>
```

What i have so far is:

```
tell application "Safari"
open location "https://teespring.com/search?q=rocker"
delay 5

set theLinks to (do JavaScript "Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.product_card')).map(function(d,i){var title = d.querySelector('.product_card__title'),link =  d.querySelector('a');if(title && link && /Rocker/gi.test(title.textContent)){return link.href}})")

end tell

return theLinks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace yourSearchTerm with whatever you want to search below:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".product_card"))
    .map(function(d,i){
        var title = d.querySelector(".product_card__title"),
            link =  d.querySelector("a");
        if(title && link && /yourSerchTerm/gi.test(title.textContent)){
            return link.href
        }
    })
```

For all your divs with class of `"product_card"` it will return an array containing the `href`s, for the ones it could find, otherwise `undefined`

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/gc6r2h3v/1/

As apple returns the last global value it might help to change the part where you set the `theLinks` variable:

```
set theLinks to (do JavaScript "someGlobal = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.product_card')).map(function(d,i){var title = d.querySelector('.product_card__title'),link =  d.querySelector('a');if(title && link && /Rocker/gi.test(title.textContent)){return link.href}})")
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. It might be an issue with Applescript calling the js but i always get "missing value" returned. I have added the current code to my original answer with a real world link and search term. Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: I'll look into it just a sec

Comment: The fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/gc6r2h3v/1/ seems to work. I should remind that this returns an array, what is theLinks ? An array or a primitive? If you go to the link https://teespring.com/search?q=rocker and copy past the code in the console you can see the links already in an array

Comment: I checked the fiddle and it does work indeed. I think the issue is the communication between  js and Applescript. The variable theLinks in AS  should be a string in Format : {“link1“,“link2“}

Comment: wait, I think I know the problem. Applescript returns the last global value so try this `set theLinks to (do JavaScript "value = Array.prototype.slice.call.....`

Comment: i think i found the issue. Needed to define the Safari document in which the script has to search in : `set theLinks to (do JavaScript "value = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.product_card')).map(function(d,i){var title = d.querySelector('.product_card__title'),link =  d.querySelector('a');if(title && link && /Rocker/gi.test(title.textContent)){return link.href}})" in document 1)` Thanks a lot @ibowankenobi

Comment: How could i have the js just return nothing instead of undefined and how would i use search terms containing a space? Thank you

Comment: if the resulting array contains some undefined, then the best would be to chain it to filter. So: `Array.prototype...........).filter(function(d,i){return d})` The result array will only contain valid strings and no undefined. To match a string with spaces you can use `\s` wildcard. So: `/Rocker\s*Nextword/gi` etc. \s will match once, \s? 0 or once, \s+ one or as many,\s* 0 or as many...

Comment: For anyone else using this inside Applescript. You need to exit the first backslash or Applescript will throw an error. So: /Rocker\\s*Nextword/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171092/discussion-between-gto-and-ibowankenobi).