# javascript remove NULL from the result

Tags: javascript, arrays

For the sake of me i can't get the Filter (.filter(function(d,i){return d})) to eliminate "undefined" or "0" working on this array.

The script runs within a Applescript applet and should return all resulting urls as string.

```js
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".product_card"))
    .map(function(d,i){
        var title = d.querySelector(".product_card__title"),
            link =  d.querySelector("a");
            console.log(title);
            console.log(link);
        if(title && link && /Rocker/gi.test(title.textContent)){
            return link.href
        }
    })

 document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(x);
```

```html
<div class="product_card powersearch__product_card">
     <a href="/shop/XYZ" class="js-search-product-link">
  <div class="product_card__image" style="background-image:url(https://image.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="product_card__title">some rocker</div>
  <div class="product_card__meta">€14</div></a></div>
  <br>
  <div class="product_card powersearch__product_card">
     <a href="/shop/ZXY" class="js-search-product-link">
  <div class="product_card__image" style="background-image:url(https://image.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="product_card__title">returns undefined</div>
  <div class="product_card__meta">€14</div></a></div>
  <br>
  <div id="result">
```

Any help highly aprechiated

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: I see that you have only one explicit return in the if statement, the other return happens implicitly and returns undefined.

Comment: Calling `filter` might help.

Comment: @tryzniak - the script should output all URLs as string. Updated my OP with this info, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get rid of some of that inner DOM selection by making your initial `qSA` selection more specific: `".product_card a .product_card__title"`.

Then you can use `.filter()` by returning the result of checking if each element `.includes()` the `"rocker"` text. Do this *before* mapping the `.href`.

Finally, `.map()` those results to the `.href` of each `.parentNode`, since we selected the child with the text directly.

```js
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".product_card a .product_card__title"))
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("rocker")
  })
  .map(function(d) { return d.parentNode.href });

document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(x);
```

```html
<div class="product_card powersearch__product_card">
  <a href="/shop/XYZ" class="js-search-product-link">
    <div class="product_card__image" style="background-image:url(https://image.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="product_card__title">some rocker</div>
    <div class="product_card__meta">€14</div>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="product_card powersearch__product_card">
  <a href="/shop/ZXY" class="js-search-product-link">
    <div class="product_card__image" style="background-image:url(https://image.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="product_card__title">returns undefined</div>
    <div class="product_card__meta">€14</div>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="result">
```

---

And of course it's a bit cleaner with modern syntax.

```
const x = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product_card a .product_card__title"))
  .filter(d => d.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("rocker"))
  .map(d => d.parentNode.href);

document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(x);
```

Comment: Thank you @Crazy Train (ozzy lover?) that worked perfectly! Did not know where to place the filter function.

Comment: You're welcome. (ozzy/rhodes) While you could rework it to first collect the `href` strings along with some `undefined` values, I think having the `.filter()` first is a little more understandable.